# Hosting different java types of java games

Tags: java, sockets, applet, hosting

If a standard webhost will not accept java programs that allow clients to post data to a server via a socket, will they accept the same program if it was instead built into and run from a website, where no sockets are used?

Comment: You could build an API for your webapp and let your stand-alone apps communicate with it over HTTP.

Comment: Your question contains alot of blog-like background information, making it very long and harder to read. If you want people to help you, provide them with a short question, leaving out information that is not relevant to the technical question you have (this also makes the question more useful for people in the future). Also try to ask only one question, not several unrelated ones.

Comment: We will likely not be able to answer that question, as you are essentially asking us what some host will allow on his server. Ask your host, he will know

Comment: @feuerball: I haven't read into data transfer through http yet so I will do. Doing it this way surely poses an equal threat to the host? ...this isn't doubt, just curiosity.

Comment: Since you can access your webapp there must be an open port for HTTP connections. Usually port 80.

Comment: @LionC: I understand your point, I was looking for general views. It seems globally accepted in the community that hosts dont like programs opening ports, perhaps many might know if host dont mind java if it doesnt open connections.